# matplotlib visualization- positive negative proportion chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, data-visualization, topic-modeling

I'm trying to make the same chart as below and wonder if matplotlib has a similar chart to make that.

The chart below is the result of the STM topic model in the R package

I have probs values using DMR in Python:

```
array([[0.07204196, 0.04238116],
       [0.04518877, 0.30546978],
       [0.0587892 , 0.19870868],
       [0.16710107, 0.07182639],
       [0.128209  , 0.02422131],
       [0.15264449, 0.07237352],
       [0.2250081 , 0.06986096],
       [0.1337716 , 0.10750801],
       [0.01197221, 0.06736039],
       [0.00527367, 0.04028973]], dtype=float32)
```

These are the results and left is **Negative** words and right is **Positive**

Example of negative positive proportion chart:

[image: Example of negative positive proportion chart]

Comment: Alex and I have different approaches but what's *fundamentally* different comes from our understanding the array provided. Do they represent two categories for each pair (e.g neighborhood, bath experience) or do they represent the positive values/negative values for a single category (eg room service positives of 0.128209; room service negatives of 0.02422131)? In other words, does the array represent 20 categories or 10? The chart shows 30 categories so it isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create something quite close to the image you included. I understood that the right column should be negative while the right column should be positive?

First make the data negative:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0.07204196, 0.04238116],
                [0.04518877, 0.30546978],
                [0.0587892 , 0.19870868],
                [0.16710107, 0.07182639],
                [0.128209  , 0.02422131],
                [0.15264449, 0.07237352],
                [0.2250081 , 0.06986096],
                [0.1337716 , 0.10750801],
                [0.01197221, 0.06736039],
                [0.00527367, 0.04028973]], dtype="float32")

# Make the right col negative
arr[:, 0] *= -1
```

Then we can plot like so:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for y, x in enumerate(arr.flatten()):
    # Get a label from the alphabet
    label = ascii_lowercase[y]
    # Plot the point
    ax.plot(x, y, "o", color="black")
    # Annotate the point with the label
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(x - 0.036, y), verticalalignment="center")

# Add the vertical line at zero
ax.axvline(0, ls="--", color="black", lw=1.25)

# Make the x axis equal
xlim = abs(max(ax.get_xlim(), key=abs))
ax.set_xlim((-xlim, xlim))

# Remove y axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

# Add two text labels for the x axis
for text, x in zip(["Negative", "Positive"], ax.get_xlim()):
    ax.text(x / 2, -3.75, f"{text} Reviews", horizontalalignment="center")
```

Which outputs:

[image: Chart with annotated points]

You can tweak the values in the calls to `ax.annotate` and `ax.text` if you need to change the locations of the text on the plot or x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the key part of the question is. That is, are you more interested in labeling the individual points based on the category, or if you're more concerned with the unique circle with a line through it. With the array provided it's a little confusing about what the data represents.

What I've assumed is each sublist represents a single category. With that in mind, what I did was make a separate column (delta) for the differences in values and then plotted them vs the index.

```
# New column (delta) with styling
df['delta'] = df[0]-df[1]
col = np.where(df.delta>0,'g',np.where(df.index<0,'b','r'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10,7))


# Style it up a bit

plt.title('Differnece in Topic Proportion (Negative vs Positive)')
plt.xlabel('Net Review Score')

plt.ylabel('Index Number')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("Evolution of rapport of polarisation - (Aluminium).png")


plt.scatter(df['delta'], df.index,  s=None, c=col, marker=None, linewidth=2)


plt.axvline(x = 0, color = 'b', label = 'axvline - full height', linestyle="--" )
```

That gives an out of this:

[image]